# Bootstrap 3 datepicker minDate bug

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am using [Bootstrap3 : DateTimePicker](https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/)

The problem is that my current code swaps the month with the day.

**example**: using "07/08/2017 20:38" as input, the calendar
sets the minDate to "08/07/2017 23:38"

```
  <script>
           $(function () {
               $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                   format: "DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm",
                   minDate: moment.unix(@Model.foo).format("DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm")
                });
            });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

(Bootstrap 3 DatePicker) Documentation :: MinMaxDate

> **minDate(minDate)**
>
> Takes a minDate **string, Date, moment, boolean:false parameter** and
>   disallows the user to select a moment that is before that moment. If a
>   boolean:false value is passed the options.minDate parameter is cleared
>   and there is no restriction to the miminum moment the user can select.

I would also use the [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/) library.

I had no problem obtaining the correct `Date` with the following snippet :

```
Date.parse(moment("23/12/1990 23:45", "DD-MM-YYYY HH:mm"));
```